# How to wrap a C++ function which returns a class object in C or Objective-C++

Tags: c++, c, wrapper, opencascade

I'm trying to build a viewer for my [OpenCascade](https://www.opencascade.com) application in the Cocoa Framework. The core of the code is written in **C++** and to render in the Cocoa window, I have to wrap the **C++** code in **Swift**.

I intend to do that by wrapping the **C++** code in **C** and then calling the **C** functions in **Swift**. The challenge, however, is that I have to wrap a function which returns a class object.

My function `makeCurve()` is defined as:

```
// makeCurve.cpp
Geom_BSplineCurve makeCurve()
{    
    std::string fileName = "SRCROOT/resources/NACA63015A_processed.dat";
    Standard_Integer num_coordinates = 51; // Number of coordinates
    Hydrofoil f(fileName, num_coordinates, 5, CLOCKWISE_LE);

    return f.getCurve();
}
```

Where `Geom_BSplineCurve` is a class object which is defined in the OpenCascade Library. I do not want to modify the library.

How could I proceed to wrap the above function in C?

Comment: You can allocate the object on the heap and retturn a pointer to it. That's basically your only option.